# RailsでDestoryアクションに遷移しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsで例に沿ってDestoryアクションを以下の通りlink_toメソッドで作成しましたが、Destoryアクションに遷移しません。調べたところapplication.jsに下記の記述が必要ということで記載しましたが状況は同じでした。
対処方法を教えて下さい。

index.html.erbの内容（抜粋）

```
<% @task.each do |t| %>
    <p><%= link_to t.title, task_path(t) %></p>
    <p><%= t.text %></p>
    <%= link_to "編集する", edit_task_path(t) %>
    <%= link_to "削除する", task_path(t),method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

application.jsに追記した内容

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: > `例に沿って` の例とは何でしょうか？WebサイトならURL、書籍ならタイトルなどを記載すると回答が得られやすくなるかと存じます。

Answer (score 0):

<%= link_to "削除する", task_path(t),method: :delete %>
   you are giving wrong path . check 'rails routes | grep task' in terminal, you will find exact path to destroy it

---

`<$= link_to "削除する", task_path(t),method: :delete %>`
の行で、間違えたパスを設定しています。 `rails routes | grep task` というコマンドで、調べてみてください。
おそらく正しく削除を行うためのパスが見つかるでしょう。